# Firebase Auth: can't instantiate AuthCredential

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a Master User module, which user can delete other users. I read from other questions, that if you want to delete a user, You must logged in as that user. And then, I realize that you could sign in with credential information stored by firebase auth. (for references, I use google, facebook and email method).

I also store a User entity in my Firebase Database which correspond to Firebase Auth. Here is my User class :

```
public class User {
        // variables.
        private String appId;
        private String email;
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private String photoUrl;
        private boolean isAdmin;
        private boolean isSuspended;
        private boolean isDeleted;
        private AuthCredential credential;

        // all those getters and setters go here.
}
```

Notice that I store a AuthCredential instance in my user, which I set for the first time when I sign up this user, ( or sign in with facebook and google).
Whenever I sign up / sign in, I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential
```

BUT, I check my firebase database, and the credential is inserted.

[image: 1. FirebaseAuth using email and password.]
**Firebase Auth using email and password.**

[image: 2. FirebaseAuth using google provider]
**Firebase Auth using google provider.**

My question is, what is the right method to store my user credential in firebase database and recover it again? 
Also, I don't know if what I'm doing is right, but my point is, I want to delete another user from some admin user. To do that, in my master user module, I'm gonna store my admin user credential, then I sign in as the user who will be deleted, delete myself, and the re-sign in to admin user by using stored admin user credential. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thank You for your help.

**EDIT**

I got error whenever I do this :

```
User curUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

... which is fine before I add AuthCredential instance in my user class.

Answer (score 2):

For email :

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
  .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");
```

For google you need the GoogleSignInAccount idToken [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider
  .getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
```

For facebook you need facebook AccessToken getToken() [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login)

```
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

AuthCredential is an abstract class and abstract classes cannot be instantiated, hence the error whenever you signup.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential

Answer (score 0):

`private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;`

```
   firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    //logging in the user
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //if the task is successfull 
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //start the activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class));
                    }
                }
            });
```